# Using Java installed in container 1 to run a jar in container 2

Tags: java, docker, containers

I am having two docker containers. Lets call them container 1 and container 2.
I can install stuff in only one of those. I have to run a jar file in container 1 in which I am not permitted to install anything. As such I install java in container 2 and then use

```
docker run --volumes-from container2 <all files need to run java from container 2>:<path in container 1> and then run the jar in container 1.
```

Can I Somehow do this ?

TIA

Comment: Container to container access in Docker is always done through networking. Afaik, you can't share the resources of one container in another. 

That's a pretty interesting question though. I will watch for other answers.

Comment: I am looking to install all java things in a directory in one container and then mounting it to other container and doing something like export JAVA_HOME

Comment: No, you can't do that.  Generally you don't install things in containers at all; you'd write a Dockerfile to build a custom image with the software you need.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am installing Java in the container using the dockerfile(container 2).

Comment: You could use a Dockerfile FROM directive so that _image_ 1 is based on _image 2_, if that's what you have, but I don't totally understand the "not permitted to install anything" constraint.

Comment: If I install Java in the container, there would be licensing issues. If I use FROM the container2 image is based on container 1 image and the IPR issues might still come up.